# How do i find median for the given program

Tags: c

We have to find mean median and mode for certain sets of observations we take last observation as -1 always and doesn't need to count it in the list

Sample input and ouput:
1 2 3 -1
2 2 -1(no mode)

My code

```
int mean,median,mode,i,sum=0,count=0,temp;
int obs[size];

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&obs[size] );
    if(obs[size]==-1)
    {
         break;
    } 
    sum=sum+obs[size];
    count++;

}
mean=sum/count;
printf("%d",mean);
temp=count;

if(temp%2==0)
{
    median=(obs[(temp)] /2 - obs[(temp - 1)/2])/2;
}
else
{
    median=obs[(temp-1)/2];
}
printf("\t%d",median);
```

But here median condition doesn't work what's the problem?

Comment: The `for` loop is incorrectly writing and reading to the `size` element every iteration. Besides not actually filling in the other array elements that is also wrong because it is a buffer overrun.

Comment: Employ basic debugging techniques to find the problem or at least better understand the program yourself. Run it in a debugger and step through the code line by line.

Comment: I have included #define size 50 or so in header   and mean condn appears to work but median is still showing zero

Comment: First let alone mean median condn work then I will change it to float

Comment: It's still wrong. Array indices in C start from 0. So for `int obs[size];` the valid indices are from `0` to `size-1`. Writing to out of bounds array element leads to undefined behaviour (it doesn't have to crash though it can).

Comment: Still median is zero

Comment: Then go ahead and at least try to debug it.

Comment: Note that unless you know the input data is sorted, you median finding is hit or miss, and in general will be a miss.  You have not shown any mode finding code; you should omit the related variables and commentary from the question.

Comment: Are the input value sorted ? If not, you have to sort them first. The error is that `scanf("%d",&obs[size] );` should be `scanf("%d",&obs[i] );`. That will fix the median value. You are then left to find the mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your code doesn't find the median.

In fact, it finds nothing and will crash during runtime because the way you are reading inputs into your array causes an **array index out of bound** error.

Replace `obs[size]` with `obs[i]` in the loop where you are getting the inputs into your array.

I assume that you fill the array in ascending order while entering your observations, otherwise you have to sort the array before finding the median.

And I don't understand your need to introduce the `temp` variable. Use `count` and don't ruin the code readability. I think you have a false notion that operations on `count` will change its value; it won't unless you assign those values back to `count`.

You have declared `median` as of type `int`. Make it `float` for reasons you will find below.

Getting into your code for median,

```
if (count % 2 == 0)
{
    // median=(obs[(count)] /2 - obs[(count - 1)/2])/2; --> Mistake
    median = (obs[count / 2] - obs[(count / 2) - 1 ]) / 2;
    // int median cannot handle this case because we divide two integers by 2
}
else
{
    // median=obs[(count-1)/2]; --> Mistake
    median = obs[(count / 2) + 1];
}
```

Be careful that you don't use `count - 1` instead of `count` because you have incremented the value of `count` even while reading *-1* into your `obs`. Since you have not posted that code for mode and if you think that that's not working as well then this might be the problem.

Comment: Will crash... *if he's lucky* and the OS saves him.

Comment: @DevSolar I wonder which compiler he's using which did not issue any warning

Comment: This code will help you find the mode: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/learn_c_by_examples/mode_program_in_c.htm

Comment: @GovardhanShah That's a brute force approach. If your data set is not very large then you need not worry. Otherwise there are many other optimal algorithms to find the mode because your data set is sorted before finding the median.